# load image into imageView from URL path in DB Table

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm trying to follow this this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) to add image into imageView from URL.

```
public class AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);            

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        String image_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());


        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, image);
    }
}
```

However, I have the image urls stored in my database table and would like to grab and display  dynamically in java. please kindly show me how to do this in java? Thank you so much!

Comment: no i'm just trying to find a way to do this

Comment: didnt you succeed in doing it?

Comment: This was answered by myself:
[FollowLink][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826681/how-to-receive-a-byte-array-and-convert-it-to-image-in-android/12826766#12826766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this link](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/10/save-image-in-sdcard.html)

here there is a function named showImage() which accepts a url as parameter and returns bitmap which you can use to set to the image view.

and dont forget to give the internet permission when dealing with images to be displayed from a url